# GUI Axes Handle Hold On/Off Not Working Within Callback Function - Matlab

Tags: matlab, uicontrol

Firstly, programatically, I created and `axes` object, then an empty `scatter` which is subsequently populated with data from within another callback function named `guiList` which works fine.  However, as my title states, I cannot seem to be able to get the `hold` function to work when I pass my `axes_h` handle into my callback function 'guiHold`.

Here is my scripted code for `axes` and `scatter`:

```
%% create empty scatter plot with panel
e_panel_position = [0.1 0.3 0.5 0.6];
e_panel_h = uipanel('Parent', fig_h, 'Title','Emotion','FontSize',12,'FontWeight', 'bold','BackgroundColor','white','Position',e_panel_position);

axes_position = [0.15 0.12 0.7 0.8];
axes_h = axes('Parent', e_panel_h, 'Position', axes_position);
scatter_h = scatter(axes_h, [],[], 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 .5 .5], 'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .7 .7],'LineWidth',1.5);
axis(axes_h, [-4 4 -4 4]);
xlabel(axes_h, 'Valence', 'FontSize', 12);  % 'FontWeight', 'bold'
ylabel(axes_h, 'Arousal', 'FontSize', 12);
grid on
box on
```

Here is my `guiHold` function:

```
function guiHold(hold_toggle_h, evt, axes_h)

button_state = get(hold_toggle_h,'Value');

if button_state == 1
    hold(axes_h, 'on')
    %hold on
elseif button_state == 0
    hold(axes_h, 'off')
    %holf off
end

end
```

As you may see, I have tried alternative versions of hold to try and make this 
happen.

`guiHold` is being invoked with a GUI toggle button.

EDIT:

Here is my `guiList` function that is invoked when you select an item from my `list_h` handle:

```
function guiList(list_h, evt, scatter_h)

global predict_valence
global predict_arousal

    val = get(list_h, 'value');
    a = 100;
    x = predict_valence;
    y = predict_arousal;
    N = length(predict_valence);

    for i=1:N
        if i == val
            set(scatter_h, 'XData', x(i), 'YData', y(i), 'SizeData', a);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What is the expected behavior and what actually happens? How are you invoking `guiHold`?

Comment: guiHold is being invoked with a GUI toggle button

Comment: i have not seen any relevance between your script code and your function `guiHold` ...

Comment: I think the problematic part of your code is missing. There's nothing inherently wrong with the use of `hold` here. If even `hold on`/`hold off` didn't work, it's probably the calls to the plotting functions that you want to obey the hold setting.

Comment: Ok, firstly I added more code to my question, which shows you how I update my scatter plot with data.  Secondly, I am confused as to what the relationship is between `axes` and `scatter`/`plot`, etc.  Is `scatter` a child of `axes`?  I've also passed my `scatter_h` into `guiList` and tried hold, but I get an error.

Comment: Any ideas?  I've even set `axes_h` to `global` and still the plot will not hold.